# Requirements of the inequality operator of an input/output iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, equality, equivalence

I'm creating a small tile based game. Items in the game store their location in a matrix of buckets. I've implemented this as a class template named `Grid` which contains a bucket class named `Tile`.

The `Grid` is essentially just a wrapper around a `std::vector` with various accessor methods for converting coords into index keys. It also forwards the vector's iterators so that I can loop over all `Tiles` in the `Grid`.

Sometimes though I need to only iterate over a subsection of the `Grid`. So I've implemented a small class named `Section` which takes two sets of coords in the constructor to define an AABB. The `begin()` and `end()` methods of `Section` return input/output iterators for looping over all of the tiles inside the AABB.

Its all working but I'm trying to keep the performance of the iterators as close to a nested loop as possible. Basically using a range based for on a `Section` shouldn't be too much more expensive than:

```
for (size_t y = 0, end_y = NUM; y < end_y; ++y)
{
    for (size_t x = 0, end_x = NUM; x < end_x; ++x)
    {
        auto& tile = grid[coords_to_key(x, y)];
    }
}
```

This brings me to the point of the question. I want the inequality operator to be as simple as possible so I've implemented it like so:

```
bool operator!=(const Section_Iterator& other) const
{
    return m_coords.y < other.m_coords.y;
}
```

Since the iterator scans each row in the `Section` sequentially we know that we're 'past the end' when `iterator.y >= end.y`. This means my inequality operator works for ranged based for loops since under the hood they just check that `iterator != end`.

The implementation of the operator looks weird though. Like ***really weird.*** For example `iterator != ++iterator` may be true or false. It depends on whether the pre-increment caused the iterator to jump to the next row.

I've been looking at the standard and I think I'm in the clear since they make the distinction between equality and equivalence.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator

> Note, "in the domain of ==" means equality comparison is defined between the two iterator values. For input iterators, equality comparison does not need to be defined for all values, and the set of the values in the domain of == may change over time.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator

> Equality and inequality may not be defined for output iterators. Even if an operator== is defined, x == y need not imply ++x == ++y.

Honestly though, standardese makes my head spin. Is what I'm doing legal?

Comment: I think you're optimising prematurely and should just go with the simplest implementation that preserves the expected semantics of the `!=` operator and won't make your head hurt

Comment: This is the simplest implementation. It just not necessarily the **correct** implementation. I'm trying to find out what the standard says the correct semantics are for the `!=` operator with respect to input/output iterators since its less than clear.

Comment: My point is, why not just `return m_coords.y != other.m_coords.y;` ? Why complicate it when you haven't even shown that it's a performance bottleneck?

Comment: Because that doesn't work for floating point coords.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The Section contains min and max floating point coords. The iterator increments a set of floating point coords that are then converted to an index for the vector when the iterator is dereferenced.

I cant just use vector iterators because the tiles are all stored in the same vector one row after another. The section iterator must evaluate whether it has reached the end of the section row, skip the rest of the tiles in the grid row and then find the start of the next section row.

I can edit the pre-increment operator into the question if that'll help.

Comment: OK I think I understand. Are your `Tile`s equally spaced? If they are, you could look up a tile based on a coordinate in constant time and so your `begin` and `end` would be easy to look up as `vector::iterator`s, avoiding the need for the inequality comparison on floating point values

Comment: Ok so I see what you're saying but consider the max coords of the section are say `7.7, 7.7`. I want the loop to include the tile at `7.0, 7.0`. If I convert to an index key or a `vector::iterator` then the last tile at `7.0, 7.0` will compare equal to the past the end at `7.7, 7.7` because the conversion from coords to index truncates to integers. Using `std::ceil` is very expensive.

Comment: @Fibbles You imply elsewhere that your grid keys are based off the int-truncation of the coords, so `7.0,7.0` and `7.7,7.7` are both in `7,7`. `end` should always be off-by-1, so for `7.0,7.0` and `7.7,7.7` end should be `8.0,8.0`?

Comment: I can't just add `1.0` and cast to size_t. What if the max coords are `8.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more researching it turns out that what I was doing was not legal according to the standard.

An input iterator must be [EqualityComparable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/EqualityComparable). This means that:

> - For all values of a, a == a yields true.
> - If a == b, then b == a
> - If a == b and b == c, then a == c

With my current equality operator `a == b` does not mean that `b == a`.

To solve my problem I looked at [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), it is an implementation of an input iterator and naturally anything it does must conform to the standard. The behaviour of its equality operator is described like this:

> Checks whether both lhs and rhs are equal. Two stream iterators are equal if both of them are end-of-stream iterators or both of them refer to the same stream

Basically, if both iterators are valid they compare equal. If they are both 'past the end' they compare equal. If one is valid but one is 'past the end' they are not equal.

Applying the same logic to my `Section::iterator` was easy. The iterator now contains a bool, `m_valid`. The method `begin()` always returns an iterator where `m_valid == true` and the `end()` method always returns an iterator where `m_valid == false`.

The iterator's pre-increment operator now tests whether it is past the end and sets the bool accordingly.

```
Section_Iterator& operator++()
{
    ++m_coords.x;
    if (m_coords.x >= m_section.m_max.x)
    {
        m_coords.x = m_section.m_min.x;
        ++m_coords.y;
        m_valid = (m_coords.y < m_section.m_max.y);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

The equality operators are now very simple to understand and have consistent behaviour. Any iterator that points to a `Tile` in the `Section` is valid and compares equal to any other valid iterator.

```
bool operator==(const Section_Iterator& other) const
{
    return m_valid == other.m_valid;
}

bool operator!=(const Section_Iterator& other) const
{
    return m_valid != other.m_valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't know whether what you have done in the above is legal. It certainly has strange semantics, though, even if it is legal.

Instead, I would consider something like this to solve your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Grid
{
    std::vector<int> tiles;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
};

class SectionIterator
{
public:
    SectionIterator(Grid * grid, size_t row, size_t col, size_t endRow) :
            m_row{ row },
            m_col{ col },
            m_startRow{ row },
            m_endRow{ endRow },
            m_grid{ grid }
    {
    }

    SectionIterator & operator++()
    {
        ++m_row;
        if (m_row == m_endRow)
        {
            m_row = m_startRow;
            ++m_col;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const SectionIterator & other) 
    {
        return (m_grid == other.m_grid) 
                && (m_row == other.m_row)
                && (m_col == other.m_col);
    }

    bool operator!=(const SectionIterator & other) 
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    int & operator*() 
    {
        return m_grid->tiles[m_col * m_grid->rows + m_row];
    }

    int * operator->() 
    {
        return &operator*();
    }
private:
    size_t m_row;
    size_t m_col;
    size_t m_startRow;
    size_t m_endRow;
    Grid * m_grid;

};

struct Section 
{
    SectionIterator m_begin;
    SectionIterator m_end;

    SectionIterator begin() { return m_begin; }
    SectionIterator end() { return m_end; }
};

int main() 
{
    Grid grid{ std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, 2, 3 };
    // 1, 3, 5 
    // 2, 4, 6

    // look up start and end row and col
    // end positions are found by looking up row/col of section end and then adding one
    size_t startRow = 0;
    size_t endRow = 2;
    size_t startCol = 1;
    size_t endCol = 3;

    SectionIterator begin = SectionIterator{ &grid, startRow, startCol, endRow };
    // Note that the end iterator actually has startRow as its startRow, not endRow, because operator++ will set the iterator's m_row back to startRow so this will make it equal the end iterator once the iteration is complete
    SectionIterator end = SectionIterator{ &grid, startRow, endCol, endRow };
    for (int v : Section{ begin, end })
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this presupposes that you have some function to translate between your co-ordinates and row/col indexes in the grid. Also, the above iterates in a column-major order, but could easily be changed to iterate in a row-major order.

EDIT

To clarify how the conversion from floating point coords to indexes would work, consider the following.

I assume your tiles are defined such that each tile covers a 1x1 square of floating point coordinates. For example, tile (0, 0) covers the floating point intervals [0.0, 1.0), [0.0, 1.0) and tile (2, 2) covers the intervals [2.0, 3.0), [2.0, 3.0). I believe this is how you have described your current setup.

If you wish to iterate all the tiles within the section from (1.2, 1.2) to (4.2, 4.2), first convert these points to row, col indices via truncation:

(1.2, 1.2) = tile (1, 1)
(4.2, 4.2) = tile (4, 4)

This means you want to iterate rows in the closed-closed interval [1, 4] and columns in the closed-closed interval [1, 4]. Since iterators like the one above work with closed-open intervals, you must add 1 to the end indexes, such that the values you pass into the iterator represent the intervals [1, 5) for rows and [1, 5) for columns. Note that these intervals are actually the same as the closed-closed interval forms, but the end values represent "one past the last index you want to dereference".

EDIT #2

You indicated that you actually want to make sure that your section finishes on an open interval in floating point coordinates, so that (1.0, 1.0) to (4.0, 4.0) contains 3 tile rows and 3 tile columns, not 4.

You could do this by comparing the end index to the original value and only adding 1 if it's not an integer, so

```
float coord = ...;
size_t idx = static_cast<size_t>(coord);
constexpr float tolerance = 1e-6f;
if (std::abs(coord - idx) > tolerance)
{
    // Add 1 to make the range include the last tile
    ++idx;
}
```

Comment: Not as stated in the question text itself, but after figuring out what it is you're trying to do, I believe this solves your problem.

Comment: This is just a more limited implementation of what I already have. Using it would create more problems. I'd have to `floor` and `ceil` my floating point coords before defining a section which creates a massive overhead just to perform a `for loop`.

Comment: But you said you're currently doing the exact same conversion in the dereference operator, meaning you have to do it on every iteration of the loop. This solution does it only once, prior to starting the iteration. Surely that's more efficient?

Comment: No, in the dereference operator I'm truncating by casting to size_t. It's a hell of a lot faster than `ceil`.

Comment: Perhaps you are confused about something: In the above, I am saying to *use `size_t` as the iteration counter rather than floating point values*. This way you can perform the conversion *once, before the iteration starts*. And you don't have to deal with floating point comparisons and weird `operator!=` semantics. I have omitted the floating point values from my code because they are irrelevant to its operation once the conversion has been performed.

Comment: Consider I have a section from (1.2, 1.2) to (4.7, 4.7). If I iterate using floating point the x coord goes 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2. That's 4 tiles to a side. It makes sense because that AABB partially covers a 4*4 section. If I convert the section coords to ints I get (1,1) to (4,4). When I iterate the x coord I get 1, 2, 3. That's 3 tiles per side. To get four I'd have to `ceil` the max coords before casting them to size_t.

Comment: That's why I said you have to add 1 to the end indexes after computing them :)

Comment: How does that work if the section min and max coords are whole numbers? If I define a section as (1.0, 1.0) (4.0, 4.0) there should only be three tiles to a side. If I add 1 to the indexes there'll be four to a side.

Comment: @Fibbles please see edited. I hope this clarifies what I mean. As you have defined it I believe that the section (1.0, 1.0) to (4.0, 4.0) does in fact contain 4 tiles per side

Comment: I understand what you mean but it does not maintain the behaviour I described. To make it clearer the number of tiles to a side should be the equivalent of `ceil(max - min)`. If you get some graph paper and draw it out you'll see why it makes sense.

Comment: 1.0 to 4.0 contains 3 tiles. 4.0 is the upper bound.

Comment: @Fibbles I made an edit that I believe implements the desired behaviour. I was being a bit slow last night, but I think I understood you in the end :)

Comment: I'm guessing the magic number is epsilon? Epsilon for floating point types is not constant, it needs to be scaled with the exponent.

Comment: I just picked 1e-6 as an example value, but you're right. You could use relative comparison by replacing the r.h.s. of the conditional with `tolerance * max(coord, idx)` and this would make it work over a wider range of values. You could also get more sophisticated and compare using ULPs but it's probably not necessary for this application.